# Generate sequence number in SQL on every insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to enter primary key in table as in below format

```
YYYY/MMM/NNNNNN
```

Where, `YYYY` is the current year, `MMM` is Month , and `NNNNNN` is a sequence no from `000001, 000002, 000003, .... 999999`.

So my primary key will look like `2012/Oct/000001` or `2012/Oct/000010` ....

How can I generate this type of code..

I can get Year and Month from `Getdate()` function. But how can I manage sequence number on every insert. can you please give me logic for that?

Comment: Which DB are you using? Mysql, orcale, sqlite, ...?

Comment: I am wondering why do you want this :o

Comment: @OlafDietsche I am using MSSql..

Comment: @OlafDietsche `getdate` is definitely not mysql. T-SQL, I think.

Comment: @nawfal its one of the logic in my data entry application

Comment: @nawfal Sometimes, if you know the DB, someone could provide a better alternative.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I didn't read nawfal's question as a question to you, but to the OP.

Comment: Is the sequence number global, or is it reset for each month? e.g. 2012/ **Oct** /00000 **1**, 2012/ **Oct** /00000 **2**, 2012/ **Nov** /00000 **3** or 2012/ **Oct** /00000 **1**, 2012/ **Oct** /00000 **2**, 2012/ **Nov** /00000 **1**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the **easiest way** would be to let SQL Server handle the dishing out of consecutive numbers using an `INT IDENTITY` column - and then use a trigger to create that specific format that you need, in a separate column.

So given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleTable 
             (ID INT IDENTITY, SaleDate DATE, ComputedPK VARCHAR(25) )
```

you could use a trigger like this to compute the `ComputedPK` from the `ID` (autonumber, handled by SQL Server) and the `SaleDate` as the date column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgSampleTableInsert
ON dbo.SampleTable FOR INSERT
AS 
    UPDATE dbo.SampleTable
    SET ComputedPK = CAST(YEAR(i.SaleDate) AS CHAR(4)) + '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, i.SaleDate) + '/' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(i.ID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) 
    FROM dbo.SampleTable s
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON s.ID = i.ID
```

This approach will **not** start at 1 for each month, however - but do you **really** need that? Isn't a sequential number (even across months) good enough?

**Update:** of course, if you're using SQL Server **2012** (you didn't specify which **version** of SQL Server you're using...) - you could use a `SEQUENCE` object to handle the consecutive numbering - and you could even reset that sequence to 1 again every start of a month ....

Comment: Once you've decided to compute it, and the computation is entirely based (as here) on other columns in the same row, any reason you'd prefer to use a trigger here rather than a computed column?

Comment: I was about to ask exactly the same thing. `ComputedPK AS CAST(YEAR(SaleDate) AS CHAR(4)) + '/' + DATENAME(MONTH, SaleDate) + '/' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)`. It can even be marked as persisted, so that it is stored as were it a regular modifiable field.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: since I cannot persist the computed column (due to the *non-deterministic* nature of the formula), I felt it was more efficient to compute it in a trigger and store it - rather than having it computed every time you access the column

Comment: @hvd: actually, I **cannot** make it `PERSISTED`: `Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 - Computed column 'ComputedPK' in table 'SampleTable' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.` - the culprit is the `DATENAME` function - it's not considered deterministic...

Comment: @marc_s Oops, that's right, that *isn't* deterministic, because the month names depend on other data than what's in the table. It should work with a slight modification, but I'll test it first.

Comment: @marc_s It can be made persisted if the date name is hardcoded (`CASE MONTH(SaleDate) WHEN 1 THEN 'Jan' WHEN 2 THEN 'Feb' ... END`); it isn't deterministic otherwise because it depends on `@@LANGUAGE` and might, for example, return `'mei'` instead of `'May'` on a Dutch setup.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
      DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()),
      '/',
      DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()),
      '/',
      REPLACE(STR(((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE monthname = DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) GROUP BY monthname) + 1),6,0),' ','0')
  )
  )
```

This is <strike>untested</strike> [now tested](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e43d/2). You would have to add a monthname column (there is a way of doing this without adding a column, but this is the most convenient)

You can also cast and use addition if you don't want to rely on concat. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e43d/6

Comment: This will work ***IF*** he's using SQL Server **2012** (only - `CONCAT` is a new feature in the 2012 version)

Comment: @marc_s It might not work even then, haven't tested this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Primary Key on two columns. One of them will represent the `Daten` and the other one the `Serial number`. Set a Sequence on the `Serial` column which increases automatically. This will make it easier for you filter the Date part of the Key.

Comment: That doesn't cover him when he switches months, though.

Comment: I'm assuming the sequence should be per month, so after all the entries for October, you'd get `2012/Nov/000001`. Your solution won't do this.

Comment: The OP didnt mention this should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just consider a compound key with an identity/numeric column and a date column (or if the day is not needed, the year/month)?

This would give you the same behaviour and would probably be a bit simpler to implement/maintain

I still would like to know the reasoning behind this - just so we can make a better educated guess